# 2nd order differential equation with constant variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given the equation:

$$y'' + 9y = 18x^2 + 31$$

and I am asked to solve it. I know how to solve constant coefficients 2nd order DE, but I need a guide on the steps to solving this problem? I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend applying the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx). To use this method, we will find the general solution by first finding the homogeneous solution and then finding the particular solution. In the notation of differential equations we would write

$$y_g(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$$

to mean that the general solution is a linear combination of both the homogeneous solution and the particular solution. We will start by finding the homogenuous solution. In order to do this, set the non-homogenuous part (the RHS of the differential equation) to zero

$$y'' + 9y=0$$

and then write the auxiliary equation as

$$r^2+9=0$$

which factors into

$$(r-3i)(r+3i)=0$$

giving the roots of

$$r=0\pm3i$$

where $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta =3$. The homogeneous solution can be written as

$$y_h(x)=c_1e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)+c_2e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)$$

so that our values of $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta =3$ form the homogeneous solution of

$$y_h(x)=c_1\cos(3 x)+c_2\sin(3 x)$$

Next, find the particular solution. Our guess will be

$$y_p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$$

and the first and second derivatives are

$$y_p'(x)=2Ax+B$$
$$y_p''(x)=2A$$

Therefore, we need to substitute all of these values into the LHS of the original differential equation and find the values of $A,B$ and $C$. This will form

$$y_p''(x) + 9y_p(x)=18x^2+31$$

or

$$2A+9Ax^2+9Bx+9C=18x^2+31$$

which means that (set the coefficients of the terms on the LHS equal to the coefficients on the RHS)

$$9A=18 \implies A=2$$
$$9B=0 \implies B=0$$
$$2A+9C=31 \implies C=3$$

hence we can rewrite our particular solution as

$$y_p(x)=2x^2+3$$

so that our general solution is

\begin{align}y_g(x)&=y_h(x)+y_p(x)\\&=c_1\cos(3 x)+c_2\sin(3 x)+2x^2+3\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much for the long and clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Find your homogeneous solution by finding the eigenvalues, which are $\pm3i$

Therefore your homogeneous solution is  $$y_c= c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x$$

For the particular solution consider $$y_p= Ax^2+Bx+C$$ and plug into your equation to get $$y_p = 2x^2+3$$

Thus your solution is $$y= c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x +2x^2+3$$